# Assistance Modifying OEM Information Batch File

Tags: file, batch-file

I have created a batch file that modifies the OEM information for computers, for when I refurbish machines.

I have it to modify the OEM information and to copy logos to specific folders on the computer.  Usually OEM Logo and background images.

My question is, I need to add a line to the batch file to check and see if a folder exist, say `%windir%\System32\oem\`and if it does not exist, to create the folder so that an image can be copied to there.

I do not want it to overwrite the folder and delete anything that might exist, but I just want it check and either create folder and copy file or skip the create and just copy the file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
md "%windir%\System32\oem\" 2>nul
if not exist "%windir%\System32\oem\" echo "Error - directory missing"&pause&goto :eof
```

should do fine.

The "MD" will create the directory if it doesn't exist and the `2>nul` suppresses the error message it it does.

If it still doesn't exist (for whatever reason) then produce an error message, wait for acknowledgement and exit